# Combined weight of items in list

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, racket

I'm working in Dr. Racket, and it's my first time using a functional language so I am quite confused.

I just need to add the weights of each different "animal" in a list. 
All the different animals have a "weight" attribute, but racket won't let me access the "weight" item of any given list element because it claims it's "not defined"

What I have so far:

```
(define (zoo-weight animals)
 (cond [(empty? animals) 0]
       [else (+ (first weight)(zoo-weight (rest animals)))])) ;This is where I get the error for weight, saying it is undefined.
```

If someone could just let me know how to reference weight regardless of list item (snake-weight, cow-weight, etc) this whole functional thing is just sort of confusing.

Thanks!

Comment: `(first weight)` is trying to call the function `first` with the value of a variable called `weight`.  I don't see any variable `weight` here, so I'm not surprised that you get an error.  Did you want something like `(animal-weight (first animals))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your responses, I gave up-votes for your time. All of your answers are good, except that I'm only allowed one function, so I couldn't make a "weight" function that gets the weight of any animal. I ended up having to do it with a large "cond" statement below. I know this is less good code, but it gets the job done without having to build any other functions (which is my only option):

```
(define (zoo-weight animals)
  (cond [(empty? animals) 0]
        [(snake? (first animals)) (+(snake-weight (first animals))(zoo-weight (rest animals)))]
        [(dillo? (first animals)) (+(dillo-weight (first animals))(zoo-weight (rest animals)))]
        [(ant? (first animals))   (+(ant-weight (first animals))(zoo-weight (rest animals)))]
        ))
```

Thanks again, all of your answers helped me to get here!

Comment: You should have mentioned that restriction on the weight function from the beginning. Anyway, your solution is not ideal, you shouldn't have to switch on the type of the animal everywhere. See my answer, I updated it with some suggestions.

Comment: Is defining an inner function allowed? You can define functions inside other functions, and the inner functions won't be exposed.

Comment: @Jack And it doesn't even require nested define;  it'd be fine to do `(let ((weight (lambda (a) ((cond [(snake? a) snake-weight] ...) a)))) (reduce + (map weight animals)))`.

Comment: @Acoustic77 While the answer may not be ideal (as Óscar López pointed out), if this is the answer that worked for you, then you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234).

Comment: Yea guys, I didn't make clear all of the restrictions, which is my fault. @Jack in the beginner language of drracket you can't have a function defined inside a function

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it! try something like this:

```
(define (zoo-weight animals)
  (cond [(empty? animals) 0]
        [else (+ (weight (first animals))
                 (zoo-weight (rest animals)))]))
```

The problem is that you can't say `(first weight)`. What is `weight`? it's probably a function that applies to animals, or a variable. So, you wrote: "take the first element of `weight`". Clearly that doesn't make sense, we want to take the first animal from the list, and *then* find out that animal's weight, before advancing to the next animal in the list.

As shown above use the following expression in your procedure, it should work assuming that the function that gives us an animal's weight is called `weight` (if not, use the appropriate function - `animal-wight`, `weight-animal`, I don't know how you called it):

```
(weight (first animals))
```

**UPDATE**

Now that you mention that each animal has a different weight function, I have a couple of comments. This is a symptom of bad design, the same function should work on all kinds of animals, to avoid those long conditionals everywhere (and it'll be a hassle if we add a new kind of animal!). I don't know how the animals are currently implemented, so I can't make further suggestions. But if it's not possible to fix the current representation, at least encapsulate the conditional in a single place, like this:

```
(define (weight animal)
   ; find the correct weight function
  ((cond ((snake? animal) snake-weight)
         ((dillo? animal) dillo-weight)
         ((ant?   animal)   ant-weight)
         (else (error "Unknown animal:" animal)))
   ; apply the function to the animal
   animal))
```

Now my implementation of `zoo-weight` will work without any modification, and there's no need to duplicate the conditional wherever the weight is needed. And if writing more than one function is a problem (and I can't imagine *why* your teacher would put that restriction, functional programming *encourages* building lots of reusable functions!), we can always in-line the code:

```
(define (zoo-weight animals)
  (cond [(empty? animals) 0]
        [else (+ (let ([animal (first animals)])
                   ((cond ((snake? animal) snake-weight)
                          ((dillo? animal) dillo-weight)
                          ((ant?   animal) ant-weight)
                          (else (error "Unknown animal:" animal)))
                    animal))
                 (zoo-weight (rest animals)))]))
```

Also, borrowing from @Jack's solution, we can use a `lambda` (an anonymous function) together with the higher-order `map` procedure. This still counts as a single function:

```
(define (zoo-weight animals)
  (apply + 
         (map 
          (lambda (animal)
            ((cond ((snake? animal) snake-weight)
                   ((dillo? animal) dillo-weight)
                   ((ant?   animal) ant-weight)
                   (else (error "Unknown animal:" animal)))
             animal))
          animals)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've got a list of animals and a function `weight` that takes one animal and gives you its weight, you mgiht be better off using `apply` and `map` here instead of doing the recursion yourself:

```
(define (zoo-weight animals)
  (apply + (map weight animals)))
```

`map` takes a function and a list and calls the function once for each thing in the list, e.g. `(map sqrt '(9 16 25))` evaluates to the list `'(3 4 5)`. The `apply` function takes a function and a list and calls the function with the list items as arguments, e.g. `(apply + '(1 2 3))` is the same as `(+ 1 2 3)`. By combining the two, you get the functionality you want. It can be difficult to learn to think in terms of these patterns, but once you do the benefits are enormous. But you should get a solid understanding of the recursive pattern in Oscar Lopez's answer first, that is absolutely fundamental to understanding functional programming patterns.

#### Update

That bit about not having a general `weight` function *and* only being allowed to create one is quite the restriction. Normally in functional languages, lots of general functions and helper functions are *good* to have. You can use the anonymous function approach outlined in Oscar's answer, but I would add that it might be good to bind this function to a name in the body of the `zoo-weight` function using a `let`:

```
(define (zoo-weight animals)
  (let ([weight (lambda (animal)
                  ((cond [(snake? animal) snake-weight]
                         [(dillo? animal) dillo-weight]
                         [(ant?   animal) ant-weight]
                         [else (error "Unknown animal:" animal)])
                   animal))])
    (apply + (map weight animals)))
```

You can also achieve the same thing with an inner `define`:

```
(define (zoo-weight animals)
  (define (weight animal)
    ((cond [(snake? animal) snake-weight]
           [(dillo? animal) dillo-weight]
           [(ant?   animal) ant-weight]
           [else (error "Unknown animal:" animal)])
     animal))
  (apply + (map weight animals)))
```

This is basically the same thing as defining a separate helper function, but the `weight` function is hidden inside the `zoo-weight` function - no code anywhere outside the `zoo-weight` function can use the helper.

---

As Joshua notes, there are other higher-order functions you can use such as variants of [`foldl`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=foldl#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29). `foldl` take a function, an initial value, and a list and reduces the list to one value using the function in steps. `(foldl + 0 '(1 2 3))` is the same as `(foldl + 1 '(2 3))` which is the same as `(foldl + 3 '(3))` which is 6. In Racket, using `foldl` instead of `(apply + (map weight animals))` would look like either of these:

```
(foldl + 0 (map weight animals))

(foldl (lambda (animal acc) (+ acc (weight animal))) 0 animals)
```

Racket also offers the [`for/fold`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html?q=for%2Ffold#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Ffold%29%29) macro, which can make the logic clearer at times:

```
(for/fold ([sum 0]) ([animal animals])
  (+ sum (weight animal)))
```

This folding function based on Common Lisp's `reduce` works as well:

```
(define (reduce f xs #:key [key-func #f])
  (let ([xs (if key-func (map key-func xs) xs)])
    (foldl f (first xs) (rest xs))))

(reduce + animals #:key weight)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what constraints Racket puts on argument list lengths, but it's generally better to `(reduce + ...)` than to `(apply + ...)`.  (`reduce` is also known as `foldl`.)  In Common Lisp, `reduce` even takes a key argument, so it's easier to combine the two: `(reduce + animals :key weight)`.

Comment: `reduce` isn't in Racket or Scheme, and it's different than `foldl` in that it assumes the first item of the list is the initial item. It's trivial to define it as `(define (reduce f xs) (foldl f (first xs) (rest xs)))`, and adding key-function support wouldn't be difficult. The problem is the OP can't define helper functions.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not defined in Racket or Scheme, but (i) for summing a list, where the "initial element" should be zero, it's not much of a problem, and (ii) Stack Overflow is about general programming questions--the OP not being able to define auxiliary functions is an artificial constraint;  most programmers will be able to, so including mention of it is useful.